# C# Can I use partial classes to make code more readable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

So for example I have this Web Api controller class `AdministratorController` and it contains a lot of tasks:

- Create
- Delete
- Edit Password
- Update
- Get
- Get all
- Etc...

Now I have all these Tasks in 1 file `AdministratorController.cs`. But with all comments and annotations the file is pretty long.

***Is it a good method to split this controller up into `partial class` pieces*** to make developers that search for a specific function get quicker to their destination? Or is this abusing the `partial` keyword
So for example I have a folder structure of:

- --Controllers
- ⠀|-- Administrators
- ⠀⠀⠀⠀|-----AdministratorCreateController.cs
- ⠀⠀⠀⠀|-----AdministratorDeleteController.cs
- ⠀⠀⠀⠀|-----AdministratorEditPasswordController.cs

Comment: Sure you can. However from an OOP-view it seems your class should be split into multiple classes anyway. However there´s no genereal "yes" or "no" here, making this a bad question for stackoverflow.

Comment: Can you? Sure. Should you? It depends. From what I see, it might be a good idea to split it, but you might come across the other side of the coin: too many files and a hard-to-navigate project. You must structure it thoughtfully.

Comment: I think it isn't real problem. Every IDE has navigation controls to navigate code.https://pasteboard.co/Igbu9ni.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously, this is a opinionated answer. Technically speaking, yes you can. It will compile.

I think you are right to split this into multiple files if it gets to long.

You could have partial classes. Or you could just have multiple classes. No one forces you to put all those methods into a single controller.

Personally, I'd opt for the multiple classes for practical reasons. You probably do dependency injection and you probably do it via constructor injection, because this is the default. With partial classes, which just means one big class but multiple files, you now need to edit your current file, *plus* the file that the constructor resides in to add a new service. It also means all the methods will need the `DeleteDataService` injected, although only the `Delete` method uses it. If you had one controller per method, you'd have the constructor in the same file *and* the other classes are not dependent on it.

But if for example you do injection via `[FromService]` attribute in your method then there is little difference between your two choices.

Structuring them in different files if keeping them in one file is too long is *good*. So good, that I don't think it would be too bad, even if you picked the "wrong" method to do it. So pick the one that seems most practical to you.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I had it in 1 controller is because of depenency injection and otherwise I had to place the exact same constructor in every controller class as all these methods use the same dependencies. 
But if that is the way to go, then I'm going to do that.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood everything correctly, but wouldn't an abstract parent class help, that requests the dependencies which every child implementation can access then?

Comment: @Nicolas Sure, you could also have one partial file hold the constructor and properties. My point is that then this dependencies will be shared (if one method needs another one, all will get it) and you always need to work in two files to change one method if dependencies change.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "readable." To the extent that we must read a class, whatever we have to read doesn't become less by being placed in separate files. There's just as much to read either way. It could even be a nuisance looking through parts of a class across separate files looking for a particular member.

Partial classes might make us *feel* like we're separating code when we're really just making bigger classes. If we think we're making anything simpler with partial classes then they could even make our code harder to understand by encouraging us to add more to a single class while separating it into different files.

I'm not railing against partial classes. This stuff only exists if there is a use for it, and I don't mean to imply that anyone who uses them is abusing them. One example is autogenerated classes, like when we add a service reference (do we still do that?) We might make some modifications to the class, but then they get lost if we update the service reference and redo the auto-generation. If we put our custom code in a partial class then we can generate part while leaving the rest intact.